# How to exclude a folder in 7zip?

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, 7-zip

I want to compress the folder `C:\Temp` but without a specific subfolder (e.g. `C:\Temp\test`). How can I do that with 7zip?

I've come up with the following command:

```
c:\Temp>7zip a -t7z test.7z c:\temp\ -mx0 -x!c:\temp\test\*
```

but it dos not work since the output is:

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Scanning

Updating archive test.7z


Compressing  Temp\admin.PNG
Compressing  Temp\test\admin2.PNG   <<<<<< this file should not be added to the archive
Compressing  Temp\first.txt
```

Comment: Maybe what's missing is the `-r` (recursive) flag. The default is not to recurse subdirectories.

Comment: The switch `-r` did not help.

Answer (score 8):

As tested on my system:

```
7zip a -t7z -mx0 -x!test\* test.7z c:\temp\
```

If you're in the source directory, the files are stored with relative paths, so the test folder looks like `test\file1.txt`, not `c:\temp\test\file1.txt`.

Please note, with the -mx0 switch, you're not compressing the files, only copying them fullsize into the archive.

Comment: Thank you. I made it work with the command `7zip a -t7z test.7z c:\temp\ -mx0 -x!Temp\test\*`. Note the part `Temp\test\*` that differs from your command. I do not know why your command does not work for me.

Comment: I used `-mx0` switch on purpose. I just needed to do a backup on my server and I wanted minimal impact on CPU of my server.

Comment: I updated this answer, my personal experience was that I needed to specify more of the relative path in order for this to work as well

Comment: Nit: The suggested command excludes _the files_ in test, not the subfolder as the OP requested (it is in the archive but empty). To exclude the folder altogether remove the final '\*', i.e. `7zip a -t7z -mx0 -x!test test.7z c:\temp\ `

Comment: For linux terminals you must put write `-x\!` instead of `-x!`